# What tool is able to analyze images by connecting to clair?

Tags: security, clair

[This clair documentation](https://github.com/coreos/clair/blob/master/Documentation/integrations.md) indicates that a number of tools should be able to scan images:

- clair-scanner
- reg
- klar
- clairctl

analyze-local-images

All of them have been tried, but none of them seems to work. All kind of issues occurred, including this:

```
2017-09-19 11:11:23.022625 I | Analyzing faild: Could not analyze layer: 
Got response 400 with message {"Error":{"Message":"could not find layer"}}
```

Another issue that occurred using clairctl:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x518490]
```

> does this happen with all images including official like ubuntu,
>   alpine, tomcat?

Using clairctl it was possible to scan postgres an other images that are available on dockerhub, but scanning local images failed

Comment: does this happen with all images including official like ubuntu, alpine, tomcat?

Comment: Using clairctl it was possible to scan postgres an other images that are available on dockerhub, but scanning local images failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Clair-scanner](https://github.com/arminc/clair-scanner) is able to scan the images locally.

https://github.com/arminc/clair-scanner/issues/13

> ```
> docker run --net=host -d --name db arminc/clair-db:2017-09-18
> docker run --net=host --add-host postgres:127.0.0.1 -d --name clair --net=host arminc/clair-local-scan:v2.0.1
> ./clair-scanner nginx:1.11.6-alpine example-nginx.yaml http://127.0.0.1:6060 127.0.0.1
> ```